# Getting number of key:value pairs for a dict key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary with a nested dictionary as value for each key, and I want to check the size of this dictionary value.

```
dict = {
'1':{'2':3,'4':4},
'2':{'3':5,'4':3} 
}
```

For this example, I should get length_of(dict['1']) = 2

How to get that?

Comment: `len(dict['1'])` - pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Just check it with builtin `len` `len(d['1'])`

Answer (score 0):

just add this at the end

```
 print len(dict['1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total number of k:v pairs within each entry of the dictionary, you can use `sum(len(dict[k]) for k in dict)`.

However, don't use the name `dict`, since it's the built-in class name for dictionaries.